# Executing msbuild process through code gets exit code -1073741502

Tags: c#, msbuild

My application is executing MsBuild.exe using `Process.Start();` running as another user. The process is running as a service. When executing the process instantly fails and returns an error code `-1073741502`.

- I am executing my code as a service.
- No matter what user, or permissions I grant this occurs (Even as Administrator).
- The service user has both the Local Security Policy to `Run as a service` and `Impersonate another user`
- No matter what my logging methods are not called. Does this means it's failing before it even starts?
- Other executables have no problem executing in this manner.
- When not executing my code as a service it executes successfully.
- WTF is the negative error code `1073741502`??(!!) Closest thing i've found is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5366965/windows-sdk-c-sharp-debugging-process-exiting-with-error-code-1073741502).

Example code:

```
void Main(){
    var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
    {
        FileName = path,
        Arguments = args,
        WorkingDirectory = workingPath,
        CreateNoWindow = true,
        UseShellExecute = false,
        RedirectStandardOutput = true,
        RedirectStandardError = true,
        LoadUserProfile = true,
        Domain = System.Environment.MachineName,
        UserName = creds.Username,
        Password = generateSecureString(creds.Password)
    };
    var process = Process.Start(startInfo);
    process.OutputDataReceived += process_OutputDataReceived;
    process.ErrorDataReceived += process_OutputDataReceived;
    process.Exited += process_Exited;
    process.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    process.WaitForExit();
}

internal void process_OutputDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.Data);
}

void process_Exited(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var process = ((Process) sender);
    Console.WriteLine("Process has finished execution, exit code '{0}'.", process.ExitCode);
}

private SecureString generateSecureString(string password)
{
    var secure = new SecureString();
    foreach (var c in password.ToCharArray())
    {
        secure.AppendChar(c);
    }
    return secure;
}
```

Any help would be really appreciated. Seems to be a permissions/local security policy issue, but without knowing more it feels like i've reached the "definition of insanity" point of my troubleshooting where i'm just repeating the same actions expecting a different result.

When investigating the Event logs I see the following exception (vague as hell):

```
Faulting application name: msbuild.exe, version: 12.0.31101.0, time stamp: 0x545443d5
Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 6.3.9600.17668, time stamp: 0x54c846bb
Exception code: 0xc0000142
Fault offset: 0x0009e052 
Faulting process id: 0x3e8
Faulting application start time: 0x01d065cdac34cc77
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\Bin\msbuild.exe
Faulting module path: KERNELBASE.dll
Report Id: ecce8b9d-d1c0-11e4-80d7-00155d611ee6
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

Comment: The error code is 0xC0000142 == STATUS_DLL_INIT_FAILED. Check eventlog (eventvwr.msc) to get any additional details about specific DLL that failed to initialize.

Comment: ProcMon with a ProcessName = msbuild.exe filter might also help, if you haven't considered that yet.

Comment: Three things: 1) load user hive by setting `startInfo.LoadUserProfile = true`; 2) Ensure the working directory where you are lauching a process has ACLs to allow access to the user account; 3) Ensure your service is executing under account different than LocalSystem -- a SystemService would work, as would any custom user.

Comment: @S.T. Can confirm using `LoadUserProfile=true` can confirm the user has `Modify` rights and the service is operating as fresh account as a members of `Administrators`.

Comment: Beginning to wonder whether this is a new .Net 4.5 security requirement that blocks services from impersonating the execution of processes http://stackoverflow.com/a/15688675/115749

Answer (score 1):

According to this thread ( [Why is this process crashing as soon as it is launched?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15581142/why-is-this-process-crashing-as-soon-as-it-is-launched/15688675#15688675) ), starting a process from a service may result in the native `CreateProcessWithLogonW` API call which seems to be not working from a service.
I just found this thread because I think I'm facing a similar issue but with the powershell start-process commandlet running in a service (which probably make use of `CreateProcessWithLogonW` internally.